# Killbackground Process actually killing the Process?

Tags: android

I am trying to test the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471239/android-task-killer) While there are no errors, I tried to see if it will actually kill a process. What I did, is I set my device to run Skype. I run my App, but Skype is still there.

I was wondering if there are problems with the function I wrote here?

Thanks.

```
public void removeProcess() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningServiceInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningServices(100);

    Log.d("total_process", Integer.toString(taskInfo.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < taskInfo.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("process_names", taskInfo.get(i).process);
        am.killBackgroundProcesses(taskInfo.get(i).process);
    }
    Log.d("total_process", Integer.toString(taskInfo.size()));
}
```

Comment: Put the package name inside `m.killBackgroundProcesses(package_name)`.

Comment: @g00dy I have to put the List element in a ComponentName?

Comment: see this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String) . Also add the permissions to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill all background process like this :

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
{
    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
}
```

But there are many applications like Email, Google Maps instantly begin the process of restarting, it might be possible skype also doing this

Comment: Thanks. When I look at logcat, I saw in the logs that pocesses do get killed. It's hard to tell on my device since I never install much on it.