# How to close an external application from my application?

Tags: android

In my application I have CountDownTimer() (5 minutes)
I want to start an "external" application from my application (for example: Music).
Then this app (Music) closes once the counter is finished.

Is there any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite broad question. The main problem is that there is no such thing like "close application" in Android at all. Application in Android is set of components like Activities, Services, Widgets etc.
For example - if you want to close some activity - you just need to start any other activity, including launcher - this will cause moving current activity to background.
If the component you are aiming to close is service the only one possibiliby I see is just to kill the application process:
[Android task killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471239/android-task-killer)
But... this not always will work - for example - if service is marked as sticky it will be restarted by system (I suppose).

Comment: it is a parental control app, so I want to start a timer when kids launch one application. can you help me to do that?

Comment: You can try the PackageManager to examine what applications are running.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the android way**, but it can solve your problem:

After starting "music", you can find pid of that app by package name using ActivityManager and kill it using Process.killProcess, **but it's not recommended** because that may cause backfires in external apps.

If you are trying to develop parental control app, better after time estimation of your CountDownTimer() - launch your activity and block returning to previous, but it will not stop background services